discrepancy between cross-validation results and confusion matrix metrics
I have a question:   I used Stratified 10-fold cross-validation with 5 repetitions for my classifying models, and it reports the results.   The problem is that when it plots the confusion matrix and I manually calculate the accuracy and other metrics from the matrix, they differ from what is reporte
I tried to aggregate all results and use the exact same results for plotting confusion metrices but it didn't work

Hello, can you share your code and the different metrics, confusion matrix, etc that you are talking about. This is very hard to bring you some help without this.

It is impossible to answer your question as you don't show any code so we have no idea what you did, the results you got and how you compute things. But I wonder if you are comparing metrics on the same dataset.
